# running errbit with ngninx and passenger with ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I've got things configured so that I can login & access errbit running on nginx with ssl

My problem is that I cannot work out how to set my rails app's errbit.rb so I can run the test

the nginx.conf looks a bit like:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate stuff.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key stuff.key;

    server_name  www.whatever.org;

    location / {
      root /web/stuff;
    }

    location /errbit {
      root /webapps2;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env development;
      passenger_base_uri /errbit;
    }
}
```

So www.whatever.org/errbit shows errbit

The initializers/errbit.rb looks like:

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key            = 'code'
  config.host           = 'www.whatever.org/errbit'
  config.port           = 443
  config.secure         = config.port == 443
end
```

And running bundle exec rake airbrake:test gives:

```
...

Started GET "/verify" for  at 2012-09-25 20:37:22 +0100
Raising 'AirbrakeTestingException' to simulate application failure.
** [Airbrake] Failure: Net::HTTPNotFound
** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.2] [Rails: 3.1.1] [Env: staging]
** [Airbrake] Response from Airbrake: 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.3.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and no message reaches errbit

Is this just a non starter, or is the /errbit the problem? SSL? Using the wrong port?

Any suggestions gratefully received

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, turned out I had a proxy blocking server https requests to the errbit api.

If you do have a proxy blocking connections you will need to add to the errbit.rb:

`config.proxy_host="1.2.3.4"`

`config.proxy_port=1111`

Essentially when there is a server error the connection is pushed out from the server to the interweb which most standard proxy configurations will block.  Adding this proxy configuration does not impact client side errors (javascript errors) as the proxy config is not used (and rightly so) in the airbrake notifier javascript for errbit (that sits on the client machine).

Another option available is if your errbit application is internal (which it should be unless you know what you're doing) you could add the internal address of the errbit api to the etc/hosts file on the server your app is running.  This would stop the application from trying to connect out of the internal network bypassing the proxy.  Having said this you would not be able to catch client side errors

to add to the etc/hosts file add:

`1.1.1.1 https://www.whatever.org`

Hope this helps